New 200A Service to Barn/Workshop
I am having a barn built and plan to install 200A service, doing most of the work myself. My property is zoned agricultural, so I do not need an inspection by the County. Nonetheless, I intend to hire an electrician to examine my work (before connecting the meter) in order to ensure I did everything safely.
I'm comfortable with electrical work generally, but have a couple questions pertaining to installing new service so I can (hopefully) get it right the first time before calling the electrician out.

Grounding the main panel. I'll drive two 5/8 copper ground rods at least 6 feet apart outside, and connect them with a #6 AWG copper wire, attached to each rod with the standard screw clamps. Question: Should the #6 AWG then run to the ground bus on the new main panel? If not, where?

The main panel will be inside the barn, backing up to the meter box on the outside. My plan is to use the knockouts in the back of the meter box and the back of the panel box to run the service wires (three (3) 2/0 copper lines, two hots and one neutral) out the back of the meter box and into the back of the main panel box. Questions about this:


(a)  Given the girth of 2/0 wire, is it realistic to make such a sharp turn within a few inches from the back of one box into the back of the other?
(b)  Do I need some sort of bushing to protect the wire from the metal edge of the knockouts?
Note on #2: The power company's design specs specifically allow for the service wires to exit the rear knockouts, but all the installations I recall seeing (including the one on my house) have the service wires running out the bottom of the meter box through a ~24"conduit run, then into the exterior wall via a right angle conduit fitting with access for pulling the wire. I can see how this would be helpful if the main panel isn't right behind the meter box. But since my main panel will be right behind the meter box, I don't see any utility to routing the wires out the bottom of the meter box.
Editing to respond to comments below:

What state (and possibly relevant what county as well) are you in? Which edition of NEC? That's all very important because you may be required to have an outside disconnect, which typically (but not always) means using a meter/main outside instead of just a meter box, which may change where the ground wire goes, etc.

I'm in Virginia, which uses the 2020 NEC. This is a pole barn, not a dwelling, so no outside disconnect required.

Your power company specs for the meter box will be law over whatever you have seen before. Depending how far along with the barn building, quite a few places prefer eufi grounding compared to ground rods now, grounding done attaching the ground wire to the foundation's rebar.

It is a pole barn, so no foundation/rebar. Thus grounding via the copper rods. Power company is Northern Virginia Electrical Cooperative.

Your power company specs for the meter box will be law over whatever you have seen before.  Depending how far along with the barn building, quite a few places prefer eufi grounding compared to ground rods now, grounding done attaching the ground wire to the foundation's rebar.

Ufer but yeah -- generally speaking, a concrete-encased electrode is the way to go for grounding.  And yes, what is your power company, and what NEC edition is your county using?

Responses to comments added to original post above.

Your code reference for bending is 312.6 - link is to the Texas 2023 code but this section of code has been pretty stable for a while.
Based on your description it sounds like you could take that path for the wire. I'd still consider doing it the way you've seen other installs done just for neatness and future serviceability reasons. You can measure everything in your plan and see if you can hit the minimum bend radius everywhere without making yourself a huge headache.
Protection should always be used on a knockout. 300.4 is your code section there.
Review 250.66 for your grounding electrode questions. The ground bar inside the service equipment is a fine spot to land the wire from the electrodes.
